# Rtmp streaming not playing on VLC player

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, rtmp

In terminal :

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x720 -r 30 -b:v 1500k -bufsize 1500k -maxrate 7000k -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.6:1935/live/test
```

I get:

> Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://192.168.1.6:1935/live/test':
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
> Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 1500 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
> Side data:
> cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7000000/0/1500000 buffer size: 1500000 vbv_delay: -1
> frame=  115 fps=0.1 q=21.0 size=    3088kB time=00:00:17.96 bitrate=1407.9kbits/s speed=0.0141x

When I open `VLC player` and open network stream in network `rtmp://192.168.1.6/live/test`, but **it does not play it shows no error it just keeps on loading**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you are trying to convert h264 to flash and view it over http/tcp? What exactly is the objective here? Also please enter the output in a code block ... it makes it more readable just like the ffmpeg above.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
rtmpdump -v -r "rtmp://192.168.1.6:1935/live/test" -o - | "vlc" -
```

https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTMPDump